# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript

Below javascript snippet is giving error on .done statement. Error is   "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function "
Since we can use done with promise any idea why this error is coming?

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject)
                {

                    if(true)
                    {
                        console.log("1");

                    }
                    else
                        console.log("2");


                });
    promise.then( function(data1) {

                     if(true)
                    {
                        console.log("3");
                    }

                    else
                       console.log("4");
                })
                .then( function(data2) {

                     if(true)
                    {
                        console.log("5");
                    }
                    else
                        console.log("6");

                })
               .done( 
                    function(response) {
                       console.log("done")
                    });
                .fail(
                    function() {
                        console.log("fail");
                    });
```

Comment: Look at the docs for that promise library, the only standard method on a Promises/A promise is `then`. JQuery promises have `done` and `fail` methods though.

Comment: Your code has a syntax error: a leading `;` after the `done` call.

Comment: @donal Jsfiddle is not showing any error. I removed ; but still getting it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method `done` nor `fail` in the Promise API, only `then` and `catch` at the object level: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Methods

> **Promise.prototype.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)**
>
> Appends fulfillment and rejection handlers to the promise, and returns a new promise resolving to the return value of the called handler.
>
> **Promise.prototype.catch(onRejected)**
>
> Appends a rejection handler callback to the promise, and returns a new promise resolving to the return value of the callback if it is
> called, or to its original fulfillment value if the promise is instead
> fulfilled.